# Application of Goldstine's Theorem to Metrization

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, weak-convergence

I know Goldstine's theorem in the form

> Let $E$ be a Banach space, then 'closed' unit ball $\mathbb{B}_E$ has closure $\overline{\mathbb{B}}_E = \mathbb{B}_{E^{**}}$ in the weak star topology $\mathbf{w}^*(E^*)$ of the double dual space $E^{**}$.

I embed $E$ into $E^{**}$ implicitly by natural isometry.

My question: is it correct to extend this result to:

> $\big(\mathbb{B}_E, \mathbf{w}(E) \big)$ is metrizable iff  $\big(\mathbb{B}_{E^{**}}, \mathbf{w}^*(E^*) \big)$ is also metrizable ?

The main foundation of this idea is the fact that
$\mathbf{w}(E)$ is generated be sets of the form
$ A_{f,r} = \{  x \in E : | f(x)|  < r  \} $ where $f \in E^*$ and $r^*$. Similarly, $\mathbf{w}^*(E^*)$ is generated by the sets of the form $ A_{f,r}^{**} =\{ x \in E^{**} : |x(f)| < r \}$, which provides natural correspondence between open sets of the topologies. Moreover, by the structure of the natural isometry embedding for all $x \in E$ it holds $x \in A_{f,r} \iff x \in A^{**}_{f,r}$.

The proof goes:

$(\Leftarrow)$

Assume that $\mathbf{w}^*(E^*)$-topology of the ball $\mathbb{B}_{E^{**}}$ is metrizable. Then the subspace topology on $\mathbb{B}_E$ coincides with $\mathbf{w}(E)$-topology, so the latter is metrizable.

$(\Rightarrow)$

Assume that $\mathbf{w}(E)$-topology of the ball $\mathbb{B}_E$ is metrizable. Then by the previous observation $\mathbf{w}^*(E^*)$ topology on $\mathbb{B}_E$ is also metrizable as it is basically the same topology. By Goldsitine this space is dense in $\mathbb{B}_{E^{**}}$. If $d$ is the distance providing metrization, I want to extend it to $\mathbb{B}_{E^{**}}$ by $d'(X,Y) = \lim_{n \to \infty} d(x_n,y_n)$ for $x$ and $y$ being a sequences in the $B_E$ such that $X = \mathbf{w}^*(E^*)\,\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$ and  $Y = \mathbf{w}^*(E^*)\,\lim_{n \to \infty} y_n$. Or I want to say that $\mathbb{B}_{E^{**}}$ must be homeomorphic to a subspace of some completion of $(\mathbb{B}_E,d)$ and hence metrizable. However, I do not know how to show that sequences like $x_n$ or $y_n$ are Cauchy for $d$ (are they have to be Cauchy at all? I think they must. We can use decreasing radius argument for a collection of neighborhoods of $X$.). I am not sure about this argument.

Comment: You need to use something more, for example $\mathbb{R}$ is metrisable in its usual topology, but its Stone-Čech compactification $\beta\mathbb{R}$ isn't.

Comment: Thank you! This is a good example for rejecting naive idea of every  topological space with dense metrizable subspace being metrizable itself. But $\mathbb{B}_{E^{**}}$ is not exactly $\beta \mathbb{B}_{E}$, so I hope that this theorem still can be proved without application of classical weak metrization theorems. However, this spaces still have something similar.